# Hover box in bootstrap - width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am newbie in bootstrap and I have one problem.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
     <a href="">
       <div class="box">
         aaa
       </div>
       <div class="hover">
         <div class="text">bbb</div>
       </div>
     </a>
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
     <a href="">
       <div class="box">
         aaa
       </div>
       <div class="hover">
         <div class="text">bbb</div>
       </div>
     </a>
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
     <a href="">
       <div class="box">
         aaa
       </div>
       <div class="hover">
         <div class="text">bbb</div>
       </div>
     </a>
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
     <a href="">
       <div class="box">
         aaa
       </div>
       <div class="hover">
         <div class="text">bbb</div>
       </div>
     </a>
  </div>
</div>

.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 60px;
}
.hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(20, 245, 43, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ocqpsvvc

Why if I use "width: 100%" for div.hover then background is outside of tag a? Background for div.box is ok.

I don't want use width with pixels or modify % because I would have modify this for all responsive layouts.

Comment: You need to put those columns inside a `<div class = "row"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not taking into account the `15px` bootstrap default padding.

add `width: calc(100% - 30px);` to make up for the padding. the `calc` is saying, make the width 100% minus 30px for the 15px right and 15px left. this will solve your issue.

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/ocqpsvvc/5/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the bootstrap "col" elements.
By default, these have padding on them, you will need to remove the padding.
E.G.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="padding:0;">
```

EDIT:
Or add another class to the element so that css can remove the padding which will be cleaner.
E.G.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 removePad">
.removePad{padding:0;}
```